# Fill tool settings in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, filling, flow-accumulation, sink

Specific question on Fill tool in ArcGis 10.2.2, I got a filling problem, I think holes are not fully filled when I use the fill tool, how do I change that ?

2 images of the same area for an example, in green, manually delimited sinkholes[image: flow accumulation, you can see there is a concentration of flow in 1 point]

[image: difference between fill tool and original DEM, you see in the same red circle there is no fill why ? how do I change that ?]

Image 1: flow accumulation, you can see there is a concentration of flow in 1 point

Image 2: difference between fill tool and original DEM, you see in the same red circle there is no fill why ? how do I change that ?

I changed Z limit without any change

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried leaving Z limit parameter as it is (0) by default? This should fill all depressions no matter how deep they are.

Comment: can you upload the second image with zoom to the problematic area and symbology for extent only. It might help to see the "hole" better, and relate to your question better.

Comment: Yes I've tried to let the Z-limit by O. and Ithought it would fill every depression too, but apparently it's not or I don't understand the way the tool is working.

Comment: @dof1985 I put the image of the filled zone on the hillshade  and the second zoom, legend is not visible but the blue represent no filling, and when I go to ID, it's confirmed that there is 0.0000 filling in the middle green delimited depression

Comment: @raphaelvallat have you tried running the sink tool on your raster. Maybe extracting a smaller extent would fast things up and hel identify if there is a snk, and what are its attribues...

Comment: @dof1985 Yes I've tried, sink tool is useless in my case, it does only find holes of 1-2 pixels even after a filter

Comment: @RaphaelVallat - I guess that if you could provide a link to the data, I could look into it more carfully - currently out of further ideas/suggestions